# java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making a game with socket connection. I stored the ObjectInputStream in a HashMap with the players name.
For each player i start a thread which keeps hearing on the ObjectInputStream of the player.

```
for(Entry<String, HashMap<ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream>> a : players.entrySet()) {
    for(Entry<ObjectInputStream,ObjectOutputStream> b : a.getValue().entrySet()) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new gameCoreListener(a.getKey(),b.getKey(),b.getValue()));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

And here's the gameCoreListener Thread code

```
public class gameCoreListener implements Runnable {

ObjectInputStream inObj;
ObjectOutputStream outObj;
String myName;

public gameCoreListener(String myName, ObjectInputStream inObj, ObjectOutputStream outObj) {
    this.inObj = inObj;
    this.outObj = outObj;
    this.myName = myName;
}

public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        Object myBitd;
        while ((myBitd = inObj.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println(myBitd.toString());
            System.out.println(myBitd);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(myBitd));

            System.out.println((int) myBitd));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The ObjectInputStream and the ObjectOutputStream are initialized one time and passed as parameters in new Threads and methods without changing. When the game starts, the client does this :

```
outObj.writeObject(21);
```

Then the Server gives an exception, the specific output :

```
java.lang.Integer: static final long serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920L;
java.lang.Integer: static final long serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920L;
java.lang.Integer: static final long serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920L;
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

When printing the Object which contains the response from the Client i can see that it's a Integer so it's strange that casting it as int gives a ClassCastException.

Comment: So obviously, the value written to the stream is not an `Object`, but a *primitive*, which means you need to call `readInt()`, not `readObject()`. Why did you think `writeInt(myInt)` is a shorthand for `write((Integer) myInt)`? [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeInt-int-) says: *Writes an int value, which is comprised of **four bytes**, to the output stream.*

Comment: I understand it but in other pieces of the program it works fine when i  read an int with `readObject()`...

Comment: You can't use `readObject` to read what was written with `writeInt`. The `readXxx` methods **must** match the `writeXxx` methods, in the *same* order. So if it works in other places, perhaps those other places is reading a stream that was written using `writeObject`, not `writeInt`

Comment: Right, i switched `readObject` with `readInt` and `writeObject` with `writeInt` but the client doesn't receive any int

Comment: Storing an `InputStream` for later use just sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: NB Looping while `readObject()` doesn't return null is not valid. It can do that any time. You need to loop until you catch `EOFException`.